# Parse emails using antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've tried for an entire week to build using antlr a grammar that allows me to parse an email message.

My goal is *not* to parse exhaustively the entire email into tokens but into relevant sections.

Here is the document format that I have to deal with. `//` depict inline comments that are not part of the message:

```
Subject : [SUBJECT_MARKER] + lorem ipsum...
// marks a message that needs to be parsed.
// Subject marker can be something like "help needed", "action required"

Body: 

// irrelevant text we can ignore, discard or skip
Hi George,
Hope you had a good weekend. Another fluff sentence ...
// end of irrelevant text


// beginning of the SECTION_TYPE_1. SECTION_TYPE_1 marker is "answers below:" 
[SECTION_TYPE_1]

Meaningful text block that needs capturing, made of many sentences: Lorem ipsum ...

[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.
[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.
[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.

[SECTION_END_MARKER] // this is "\n\n"

// SENTENCE_MARKER can be "a)", "b)" or anything that is in the form "[a-zA-Z]')'"
// one important requirement is that this SENTENCE_MARKER matches only inside a section. Either SECTION_TYPE_1 or SECTION_TYPE_2


// alternatively instead of [SECTION_TYPE_1] we can have [SECTION_TYPE_2].
// if we have SECTION_TYPE_1 then try to parse SECTION_TYPE_1 else try to parse SECTION_TYPE_2.enter code here

[SECTION_TYPE_2] // beginning of the section type 1;

Meaningful text bloc that needs capturing. Many sentences Lorem ipsum ...

[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.
[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.
[SENTENCE_MARKER] - Sentences that needs to be captured.

[SECTION_END_MARKER] // same as above
```

The problems I'm facing are the following:

- I didn't figure out a good way to skip text at the beginning of the
  message and start applying the parsing rules only after a marker has
  been found. SECTION_TYPE_1
- Capture all the text inside a section between section start and the sentence markers
- After a SECTION_END marker ignore all the text that comes afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antlr is a parser for structured, ideally unambiguously structured, texts.  Unless your source messages have relatively well-defined features that reliably mark the message parts of interest, Antlr is unlikely to work.

A better approach would be to use a natural language processor (NLP) package to identify the form and object of each sentence or phrase to thereby identify those of interest.  The [Stanford NLP package](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/) is quite well known ([Github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp)).

*Update*

The necessary grammar will be of the form:

```
message : subject ( sec1 | sec2 | fluff )* EOF ;

subject : fluff* SUBJECT_MARKER subText EOL ;
subText : ( word | HWS )+ ;

sec1    : ( SECTION_TYPE_1 content )+ SECTION_END_MARKER     ;
sec2    : ( SECTION_TYPE_2 content )+ SECTION_END_MARKER     ;
content : ( word | ws )+ ;

word    : CHAR+ ;
ws      : ( EOL | HWS )+ ;

fluff   : . ;

SUBJECT_MARKER      : 'marker' ;
SECTION_TYPE_1      : 'text1' ;
SECTION_TYPE_2      : 'text2' ;
SENTENCE_MARKER     : [a-zA-Z0-9] ')' ;

EOL                 : '\r'? '\n';
HWS                 : [ \t] ;
CHAR                : . ;
```

Success will depend on just how unambiguous the various markers are -- and it is a given that there will be ambiguities. Either modify the grammar to handle the ambiguities explicitly or defer to the tree-walk/analysis phase to resolve.

Comment: Agreed about the NLP approach. My messages however have specific features I can rely on. The email setup of the organisation is to use a particular template for emails that fall in about 10 categories. The markers are always present. The only variable part is the text in between the markers.

Comment: A solution may be possible with Antlr. Need to list the full set of features in your Q and post your grammar attempt to recognize them.

Comment: Ok. I've updated the message template. Sorry for the delay. I didn't manage to build any grammar that allows me to parse this message type.

Comment: Updated. Qs re specific implementation problems should probably be addressed separately.

Comment: So awesome. Thank you!